# Set generated by $a+b-c$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let
$\Lambda \subset \mathbb{R}$ is a countable set, i.e. $|\Lambda|\leq \aleph_0$ and  $\Lambda$ satisfies that if $\lambda_1, \ \lambda_2, \ \lambda_3 \in \Lambda$ then $\lambda_1 - \lambda_2 + \lambda_3 \in \Lambda$.

Is there a characterization of such set (what are the possibilities for $\Lambda$)?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you think of some initial examples?

Comment: (Also, what you call enumerable is normally called countable.) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set?wprov=sfti1

Comment: I know that for instance, if 1 and 2 are in $\Lambda$ then $\Lambda = \mathbb{N}$. Also $\Lambda$ can be formed by multiples of an integer. I'm interested in the general theory (if any) for my research.

Comment: Technically, in that case $\mathbb N\subseteq \Lambda.$ But show work in your question to get a better response for your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general $\Lambda$ is empty or a coset of a countable additive subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$.  It is clear that such sets satisfy your property.  It remains to show that any set $\Lambda$ satisfying your property has this form:

Suppose $\Lambda\neq\emptyset$.  The set of differences of elements of $\Lambda$ forms a countable additive subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$, as if $u=x-y$ and $v=z-w$ with $x,y,z,w\in\Lambda$, then $$u+v=(x-y+z)-w.$$

As $\Lambda\neq \emptyset$ we have some $x\in \Lambda$ and $0=x-x$ and $-(y-z)=z-y$, so the differences do indeed form a subgroup.

Let $A$ denote this subgroup.  Fix $x\in \Lambda$.  Then if $u\in A$ we have $u=y-z$ with $y,z\in \Lambda$ so $$x+u=x+y-z\in\Lambda.$$

Conversely, if $z\in \Lambda$ then $z=x+u$, where $u=z-x\in A$.

Thus $\Lambda=x+A$.